# Submit a command from C- drive Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm trying to load a file using bcp utility using the below command,

```
C:\>bcp test.dbo.table1 in C:\table1.txt -t , -c -S USERNAME\SQLEXPRESS -T
C:\>bcp test.dbo.table2 in C:\table2.txt -t , -c -S USERNAME\SQLEXPRESS -T
C:\>bcp test.dbo.table3 in C:\table3.txt -t , -c -S USERNAME\SQLEXPRESS -T
C:\>bcp test.dbo.table4 in C:\table4.txt -t , -c -S USERNAME\SQLEXPRESS -T
```

THe data in table1.txt..... table5.txt is prepared by a Python module - a.py.. At the end of my module, I need to submit the above commands, so that my files are loaded. How do I accomplish it, I also need to capture the errors that the load utility generates.

Comment: Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: I think I figured out a way..Planning to create a batch file with all the commmands and from my module call the subprocess module and submit it..Thanks.